# Confused about notation of max of random variables

Tags: random-variables

Let (*N, F*) be a down-closed set system. $\forall$ e $\in$ *N*, there is a non-negative random variable $Z_e$.

I'm confused about what the following notation means:

$I^* \in argmax \{\, \sum_{e \in I} Z_e \mid I \in F \,\}$

I'm a little confused about what kind of entity $I^*$ is. What I think it means is that $I^*$ is a random set which contains each $I \in F$ with some probability. 
Am I right?

Comment: Can you define what it means to be a "down-closed set system" of random variables?

Comment: This means that, for every $\omega$, $I^*(\omega)$ is such that $$S(I^*(\omega))=\max\{S(I,\omega)\mid I\in F\}$$ where, for every $I$ in $F$, $$S(I,\omega)=\sum_{e \in I} Z_e(\omega).$$ Thus, if measurable, $I^*$ is a random variable defined on $\Omega$ with values in $F$.

Comment: Let *N* be your ground set and let *F* be a family of sets such that $F \subseteq 2^N$. A set system *(N, F)* is down-closed if, $\forall B \in F$, if $A \subseteq B$, then $A \in F$.